# Why do we need three different ways to operating in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why do we need three ways for operating?

(I use multiplication for examples)

First way:

```
df['a'] * 5
```

Second way:

```
df['a'].mul(5)
```

Third way:

```
df['a'].__mul__(5)
```

Isn't just two enough, no need an `mul`, I was wondering can it be like normal ways, like a integer

First way:

```
3 * 5
```

Second way:

```
(3).__mul__(5)
```

But in regular bases of an inetger:

```
(3).mul(5)
```

Would break.

I am just curious, why do we need this much stuff in Pandas, it's same with addition, subtraction and division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` and `mul` do the same thing, but `__mul__` is different.

`*` and `mul` perform some checks before delegating to `__mul__`. There are two things that you should know about.

1. `NotImplemented`

There is a special singleton value `NotImplemented` that is returned by a class's `__mul__` in cases where it cannot handle the other operand. This then tells Python to try `__rmul__`. If that fails too, then a generic `TypeError` is raised. If you use `__mul__` directly, you won't get this logic. Observe:

```
class TestClass:

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented

TestClass() * 1
```

Output:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'TestClass' and 'int'
```

Compare that with this:

```
TestClass().__mul__(1)
```

Output:

```
NotImplemented
```

This is why, in general, you should avoid calling the dunder (magic) methods directly: you bypass certain checks that Python does.

2. Derived class operator handling

Where you attempt to perform something like `Base() * Derived()`, where `Derived` inherits from `Base`, you would expect `Base.__mul__(Derived())` to be called first. This can pose problems, since `Derived.__mul__` is more likely to know how to handle such situations.

Therefore, when you use `*`, Python checks whether the right operand's type is more derived than the left's, and if so, calls the right operand's `__rmul__` method directly.

Observe:

```
class Base:

    def __mul__(self, other):
        print('base mul')

class Derived(Base):

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        print('derived rmul')

Base() * Derived()
```

Output:

```
derived rmul
```

Notice that even though `Base.__mul__` does not return `NotImplemented` and can clearly handle an object of type `Derived`, Python doesn't even *look* at it first; it delegates to `Derived.__rmul__` immediately.

For completeness, there *is* one difference between `*` and `mul`, in the context of `pandas`: `mul` is a function, and can therefore be passed around in a variable and used independently. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

pandas_mul = pd.DataFrame.mul
pandas_mul(pd.DataFrame([[1]]), pd.DataFrame([[2]]))
```

On the other hand, this will fail:

```
*(pd.DataFrame([[1]]), pd.DataFrame([[2]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the "magic method" `__mul__` and the operator `*` are the same in the underliying python (`*` just calls `__mul__`), and as you pointed out it is the way python stadarized handles things. The other method `mul` is a method that you can use for mapping (use `map`) and avoiding using a `lambda x, y: x*mul` for example.
Yes, you could still use `__mul__` but usually it is not the purpose of those methods (`__x__`) to be used as normal functions and a simple `mul` makes the code more clear.

So, you dont really "need" it, but it is nice to have and use.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the third way (`df['a'].__mul__(5)`) should never be used since it's an internal method that's called by a Python class. In general, users don't touch any of the "dunder" methods.

Regarding the other two ways, the first way is obvious; you just multiply the thing. It's standard math.

The second way gets a bit more interesting. One example of how I've used that method is when the function you want to apply is a variable.

For example:

```
def pandas_math(series, func, val):
    return getattr(series, func)(val)
```

`pandas_math(df['a'], 'mul', 5)` will give the same result as `df['a'].mul(5)` but now you can pass `mul` as a variable, or whatever other function you want to use. It's much easier than hard-coding all the symbols.

Comment: You could use the `operator` module if `df['a'].mul` did not exist, so it doesn't really serve a purpose in that regard.

Comment: Right, but for some reason Pandas decided to have it built in. I understood the main point being "why would I do `df['a'].mul(5)` instead of `df['a']*5`?". A similar question to "why would one use the `operator` module in the first place?"